# Facebook API won't allow subdomain

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The Facebook app's `App Domain` is set to `domain.com`. The `Site URL` is set to `http://domain.com`. Requests to the API from `domain.com` go through fine. However, requests from `lvh.domain.com` give the following error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

What am I doing wrong? Setting the `Site URL` to be `lvh.domain.com` doesn't fix the problem either.

One peculiarity is that `lvh.domain.com` points to `localhost` and is accessed at port `8000` instead of the default http port.

(`domain` subbed in for actual domain)

Comment: did you try with lvh.domain.com:8000 as site url?

Comment: @luschn Yes. Even when I do that, the only domain that works is domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Add lvh.domain.com to your list of App Domains. Your Site URL is fine if it's domain.com